# How many shortest distances change when adding an edge to a graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Let $G=(V,E)$ be some complete, weighted, undirected graph. We construct a second graph $G'=(V, E')$ by adding edges one by one from $E$ to $E'$. We add $\Theta(|V|)$ edges to $G'$ in total.

Every time we add one edge $(u,v)$ to $E'$, we consider the shortest distances between all pairs in $(V, E')$ and $(V, E' \cup \{ (u,v) \})$. We count how many of these shortest distances have changed as a consequence of adding $(u,v)$. Let $C_i$ be the number of shortest distances that change when we add the $i$th edge, and let $n$ be the number of edges we add in total.

> How big is $C = \frac{\sum_i C_i}{n}$?

As $C_i = O(|V|^2)=O(n^2)$, $C=O(n^2)$ as well. Can this bound be improved? Note that I define $C$ to be the average over all edges that were added, so a single round in which a lot of distances change is not that interesting, though it proves that $C = \Omega(n)$.

I have an algorithm for computing a geometric t-spanner greedily that works in $O(C n \log n)$ time, so if $C$ is $o(n^2)$, my algorithm is faster than the original greedy algorithm, and if $C$ is really small, potentially faster than the best known algorithm (though I doubt that).

Some problem-specific properties that might help with a good bound: the edge $(u,v)$ that is added always has larger weight than any edge already in the graph (not necessarily strictly larger). Furthermore, its weight is shorter than the shortest path between $u$ and $v$.

You may assume that the vertices correspond to points in a 2d plane and the distances between vertices are the Euclidian distances between these points. That is, every vertex $v$ corresponds to some point $(x,y)$ in the plane, and for an edge $(u,v)=((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$ its weight is equal to $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2.}$

Comment: Take two cliques connected by a path with two edges.  Adding one edge directly between the cliques shortens $\Omega(n^2)$ of the shortest paths.

Comment: @Louis: yes, there are examples in which a single edge causes a lot of distances to change, but do there exist graphs in which that happens for every edge you add, or at least for a lot of them? This is exactly why I defined $C$ to be the average over all edges :)

Comment: Most of the edges in this graph that can be added are of the type I described...

Comment: @Louis True. Cliques contain $O(n^2)$ edges though, which is more than I will ever add to my graph.

Comment: I had a same problem before, but My graph was kind of sparse graphs with $|E|=O(|V|)$ and I should to prove average changes is O(1) but I couldn't do so :-). But for your case I think if you find a relation between this and solution of APSP you can get some results.

Comment: @AlextenBrink: Replace cliques with wheels connected by a longer path and you'll get the same story...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider the following linear chain with $n+1$ nodes, $n$ edges and viciously chosen weights:

[image: example]
<sup>[[source](http://akerbos.github.io/sesketches/src/cs_1062.tikz)]</sup>

Clearly, the edges could have been added in order of their weights and there are $n \in \mathcal{O}(|V|)$ of them. Adding the dashed edge (which is legal) creates shorter paths for all pairs $(u_i,b_j)$ with $i,j = 1,\dots,k$. As $k \approx \frac{n}{4}$ and assuming that $n \in \Theta(|V|)$, both first and last row contain $\Theta(|V|)$ many nodes each and the addition causes $\Theta(|V|^2)$ many shortest path changes.

We can now move "outwards" now, i.e. add the next edge with weight $n+2$ between $u_{k-1}$ and $b_{k-1}$ and so on; if we continue this to $(u_1,b_1)$, we cause in total $\Theta(|V|^3)$ shortest path changes.

If this does not convince you, note that you can actually start this "process" with $(c_1,c_2)$ and work outwards from there; this way you add $\approx n$ edges which cause in total $\approx \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 \in \Theta(n^3) = \Theta(|V|^3)$ many shortest path changes---this is just impossible to draw to fit on one screen.

Comment: This indeed works, and furthermore, your example can be changed a bit to become Euclidian. Thanks :)